# Migrating from iptables to firewalld settings with ansible in CentOS 7

Tags: redis, centos, ansible, firewall, iptables

I'm setting up a new Redis cluster on my webservers, and currently I was adding some chain rules with the iptables settings, but now I'm switching to automatically deploying through ansible.

My iptables looks like this:

```
1 iptables -N REDIS
2 iptables -A REDIS -s 10.0.1.11 -j ACCEPT  ## Master server
3 iptables -A REDIS -s 10.0.1.10 -j ACCEPT  ## Slave 01/03
4 iptables -A REDIS -j LOG --log-prefix "unauth-redis-access"
5 iptables -A REDIS -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
6 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -j REDIS
```

In this way, I have to manually add the rule #3 to each slave server (currently there are only 3 slave servers, but it's going to be way more at some point, thus, I'm planning on automatically deploying it through ansible).

And the ansible config that I've set looks like this:

```
- name: Redis service
  tags: ['redis']
  firewalld:
        service=redis
        zone=internal
        state=enabled
        permanent=yes

- name: Redis connections
  tags: ['redis']
  firewalld:
        source=10.0.1.0/24
        port=6379/tcp
        zone=internal
        state=enabled
        permanent=yes
  notify: restart redis
```

I'm using my webservers' subnet as source, or should I list each webserver's ip as source?

Although when I deploy the ansible configuration, it doesn't work at all. Using iptables works just fine, but I have to switch it to firewalld due dev-env issues mentioned above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding 'it doesn't work at all'. Given that that is the bit that likely needs focus, and without any detail, it could have any number of things as its cause, it is hard to know where to start to assist.

Comment: Oh, sorry. When I set up like this, when I try to connect the slave to the master, it says that can't connect/can't reach the host. So basically it's like these settings aren't working at all

Comment: So firewalld is just a wrapper around iptables, so you can still use iptables to inspect the rules that firewalld has implemented, so can you check what rules Ansible added? If your firewalld is otherwise default, I would suggest that your rule needs to go in the 'public' zone, rather than 'internal'. (The zone names are counter-intuitive unless you are on a multi-homed machine that is acting as a router)

Answer (score 0):

try adding `immediate=yes` or add a service-handler to reload firewalld.
using firewalld with `permanent=yes` only changes the configuration files, it doesn't install the iptables-rules